# Como converter o valor positivo de uma aob em um valor negativo?

Tags: hexadecimal

Ola alguem pode me ajudar com a seguinte questao ?

Exemplo 
Tenho uma aob que representa  um item (cigarro) em um jogo ...

XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX = cigarro

Xx XX XX XX XX XX XX XX 01 = 1 cigarro

XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX 0A = 10 cigarros

Como transformar o valor do item em um valor negativo?

XX XX XX XX XX XX XX XX ?? = -10 cigarros

Se alguém souber me ajudar nisso eu agradeço

Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer com [Complemento de 2 em Binário](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Eletr%C3%B4nica_Digital/N%C3%BAmeros_bin%C3%A1rios_negativos).

Transforme o valor que deseja converter em binário: `0A` = 1010

Agora faça a inversão (`NOT`) do binário, ou seja, a onde é 0 ficará e 1 e a onde é 1 ficará 0:

```
1010 = 0101
```

Some +1 no resultado: `0101 + 0001 = 0110` e terá seu número negativo em binário: `0110`.

O problema agora é a identificação de um número "normal" (binário puro) e de um número negativo (`0110` em binário normal é `6`). Para resolver este problema, tem que ser utilizado o resto dos bits, por exemplo:

O número 10 em 8 bits é: `0000 1010`, ao fazer a inversão ficará `1111 0101`, soma +1 e ficará `1111 0110`, pronto,  este é o -10 negativo e "identificado" em binário (o número 6 é `0000 0110`). Entretanto isso **não funciona para todos** os tipos de valores.

Por exemplo: no caso de um **int signed** que "reserva um espaço" para a identificação de números negativos, esta operação funcionaria normalmente. Mas com um **int unsigned** (em que não tem a "reserva" para um número negativo), isto não funcionaria e o resultado seria `246`.

Agora com o seu valor, vamos lá:

Transforma para binário:

```
0000 0000 0000 000A = 0000 0000 0000 1010
```

Faz a inversão:

```
0000 0000 0000 1010 = 1111 1111 1111 0101
```

Soma +1:

```
1111 1111 1111 0101 + 0001 = 1111 1111 1111 0110
```

Agora com o número negativo binário em mãos, basta transforma para Hexadecimal: `FFFF FFFF FFFF FFF6`.

O resultado de -10 é `FFFF FFFF FFFF FFF6`. Tente utilizar este valor em seu AoB.